# How to animate the hight change of an UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In -tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: I'm changing the height for a cell dynamically during usage of the table. But I don't want this to happen like BAAANNGGG..., I want it nicely animated. Where would I put the animation block? Would that go just around the -reloadData call?

Well, at least this does nothing:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"foo" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:3];
[self.table reloadData];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

don't get any animation here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potentially the following is a better option if you're on iOS 3.0 and up:

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Change the animation to match your preference of course...